# getting while accessing gmail api from java

Tags: gmail-api

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked."
}

token has expired and i have created new Oauth2.0 client id, and verified configure consent screen
,still giving this **com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request**
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked."
}

And when i tried with postman creating new access token its giving redirecting to particular gmail account along with 400 error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHTSN.png)

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Answer (score 0):

> Token has been expired or revoked.

means just that your refresh token has expired or been revoked by the user you need to prompt the user to authorize your application again.

Comment: yes , maybe this is the problem,